# How do you refresh a Google OAuth access token using simple HTTP?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I'm getting started with the Google OAuth system using Python. I have looked through the official docs and SO, so I understand that the 'refresh' token is their solution to long-life access.

However I can't anywhere find guidance on the endpoint or method for using the refresh token. I typically use basic HTTP requests rathe than the proprietary libraries and so I just want to know the endpoint and parameters I need to send.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in [using a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) the specific HTTP URL is `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`. An example request looks like this:

```
POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsiyUH5kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: Thanks @abraham, that's perfect. Just to add some extra confusion, I don't see a section about using a refresh token on that page and can't Ctrl+F for that URL on the page either. Very bizarre!

Comment: Doh, worked it out. You have to click the HTTP tab within the code samples for the "Offline access" section. Much appreciated.

Comment: ++++++ for @PhilSheard comment -- I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure out the actual HTTP syntax and hadn't seen the HTTP tab =).